# Test fails for controller method rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I can't seem to figure out why my PartTransactions test keep failing for updating and creating. All of my other test are successful so, to me I feel like I'm maybe doing something incorrectly in my fixtures - any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

## Here are the failure results when I run my test

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 62590
Started with run options --seed 23873

 FAIL["test_should_create_part_transaction", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x00007f96615c1710 @name="PartTransactionsControllerTest">, 0.644004000001587]
 test_should_create_part_transaction#PartTransactionsControllerTest (0.64s)
        "PartTransaction.count" didn't change by 1.
        Expected: 3
          Actual: 2
        test/controllers/part_transactions_controller_test.rb:19:in `block in <class:PartTransactionsControllerTest>'

 FAIL["test_should_update_part_transaction", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x00007f966163a548 @name="PartTransactionsControllerTest">, 0.6869309999747202]
 test_should_update_part_transaction#PartTransactionsControllerTest (0.69s)
        Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <200: OK>
        test/controllers/part_transactions_controller_test.rb:38:in `block in <class:PartTransactionsControllerTest>'

  21/21: [===========================================================================================================================================================================================================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00

Finished in 0.77788s
21 tests, 26 assertions, 2 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

## Here is my schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_01_30_150153) do

  create_table "customers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "cust_id"
    t.string "cust_name"
    t.integer "cust_status"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "part_transactions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "trans_id"
    t.datetime "trans_date"
    t.decimal "trans_qty", precision: 14, scale: 4
    t.string "trans_type"
    t.string "invoiced"
    t.decimal "cs_trans_qty", precision: 6, scale: 2
    t.integer "part_id"
    t.integer "customer_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["customer_id"], name: "index_csi_part_transactions_on_customer_id"
    t.index ["part_id"], name: "index_csi_part_transactions_on_part_id"
  end

  create_table "parts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "part_id"
    t.string "description"
    t.decimal "qty_on_hand", precision: 14, scale: 4
    t.decimal "order_point", precision: 14, scale: 4
    t.decimal "reorder_qty", precision: 14, scale: 4
    t.string "part_type"
    t.string "status"
    t.string "inv_cs"
    t.decimal "cs_qty", precision: 3
    t.string "cs_status"
    t.integer "customer_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["customer_id"], name: "index_csi_parts_on_customer_id"
  end
end
```

## Here are my models

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :parts, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :part_transactions, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Part < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :part_transactions, :dependent => :destroy
end

class PartTransaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :part
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

## Here are my fixtures

```
#Customer -------------------------------------------------------------         

one:
  cust_id: one
  cust_name: My Company
  cust_status: 3

two:
  cust_id: two
  cust_name: Other Company
  cust_status: 1

#Parts-------------------------------------------------------------

one:
  part_id: one
  description: TestA
  qty_on_hand: 2
  order_point: 3
  reorder_qty: 1
  part_type: TestAPartType
  status: F
  inv_cs: 2
  cs_qty: 3
  cs_status: F
  customer: one

two:
  part_id: two
  description: TestB
  qty_on_hand: 1
  order_point: 3
  reorder_qty: 6
  part_type: TestBPartType
  status: F
  inv_cs: 2
  cs_qty: 3
  cs_status: C
  customer: two

#PartTransactions------------------------------------------------------

one:
  trans_id: one
  trans_date: 2019-01-31
  trans_qty: 1
  trans_qty: 1
  trans_type: 1
  invoiced: 1
  cs_trans_qty: 1
  cs_trans_qty: 1
  part_id: one
  customer: one

two:
  trans_id: 2
  trans_date: 2019-01-31
  trans_qty: 3
  trans_qty: 3
  trans_type: 3
  invoiced: 1
  cs_trans_qty: 1
  cs_trans_qty: 1
  part_id: two
  customer: two
```

## Here is my PartTransaction Test

```
require 'test_helper'

class PartTransactionsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @part_transaction = part_transactions(:one)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get part_transactions_url
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get new_part_transaction_url
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should create part_transaction" do
    assert_difference('PartTransaction.count') do
      post part_transactions_url, params: { part_transaction: { cs_trans_qty: @part_transaction.cs_trans_qty, customer_id: @part_transaction.customer_id, invoiced: @part_transaction.invoiced, part_id: @part_transaction.part_id, trans_date: @part_transaction.trans_date, trans_id: @part_transaction.trans_id, trans_qty: @part_transaction.trans_qty, trans_type: @part_transaction.trans_type } }
    end

    assert_redirected_to part_transaction_url(PartTransaction.last)
  end

  test "should show part_transaction" do
    get part_transaction_url(@part_transaction)
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get edit" do
    get edit_part_transaction_url(@part_transaction)
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should update part_transaction" do
    patch part_transaction_url(@part_transaction), params: { part_transaction: { cs_trans_qty: @part_transaction.cs_trans_qty, customer_id: @part_transaction.customer_id, invoiced: @part_transaction.invoiced, part_id: @part_transaction.part_id, trans_date: @part_transaction.trans_date, trans_id: @part_transaction.trans_id, trans_qty: @part_transaction.trans_qty, trans_type: @part_transaction.trans_type } }
    assert_redirected_to part_transaction_url(@part_transaction)
  end

  test "should destroy part_transaction" do
    assert_difference('PartTransaction.count', -1) do
      delete part_transaction_url(@part_transaction)
    end

    assert_redirected_to part_transactions_url
  end
end
```

## Here is my PartTransactionsController

```
class PartTransactionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_part_transaction, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /part_transactions
  # GET /part_transactions.json
  def index
    @part_transactions = PartTransaction.all
  end

  # GET /part_transactions/1
  # GET /part_transactions/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /part_transactions/new
  def new
    @part_transaction = PartTransaction.new
  end

  # GET /part_transactions/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /part_transactions
  # POST /part_transactions.json
  def create
    @part_transaction = PartTransaction.new(part_transaction_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @part_transaction.save
        format.html { redirect_to @part_transaction, notice: 'Part transaction was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @part_transaction }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @part_transaction.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /part_transactions/1
  # PATCH/PUT /part_transactions/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @part_transaction.update(part_transaction_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @part_transaction, notice: 'Part transaction was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @part_transaction }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @part_transaction.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /part_transactions/1
  # DELETE /part_transactions/1.json
  def destroy
    @part_transaction.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to part_transactions_url, notice: 'Part transaction was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_part_transaction
      @part_transaction = PartTransaction.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def part_transaction_params
      params.require(:part_transaction).permit(:trans_id, :trans_date, :trans_qty, :trans_qty, :trans_type, :invoiced, :cs_trans_qty, :cs_trans_qty, :part_id, :customer_id)
    end
end
```

Comment: You forgot to add your controller file which you're testing.

Comment: thanks @SebastianPalma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how I missed this but, I figured it out and it was caused by my part_transactions fixture - see below

I had part_id in my fixture when it should of been part (*smacks self on the head)

```
one:
  trans_id: one
  trans_date: 2019-01-31
  trans_qty: 1
  trans_qty: 1
  trans_type: 1
  invoiced: 1
  cs_trans_qty: 1
  cs_trans_qty: 1

  #should be part not part_id 
  #part_id: one
  part: one

  customer: one

two:
  trans_id: 2
  trans_date: 2019-01-31
  trans_qty: 3
  trans_qty: 3
  trans_type: 3
  invoiced: 1
  cs_trans_qty: 1
  cs_trans_qty: 1

  #should be part not part_id 
  #part_id: two
  part: two      

  customer: two
```